# Is one license enough for Civ VI LAN games?

Tags: civilization-6

Some computer games allow their users to install them on multiple computers to play a LAN game with only a single license (legally). Is this supported by Civilization VI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer looks to be **No**, but people have found some work-arounds like going into offline mode on steam. The legality of that option is another matter.

The developers actively don't want a big LAN with one copy of the game. That's why they created hotseat mode where you can can alternate on one PC.

https://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/0/215439774851870003/